# How to create custom time field in salesforce custom object?

Tags: salesforce, field, formula, custom-object

want to create a time custom time field .. how it is possible ?

Advance thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look through [Creating Custom Objects and Fields](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en/data_modeling/creating_custom_objects_fields). It should help you with current question and future ones.

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple. If you have already created a custom object in its detail page you can add custom fields.

And if you want your date field to be populated automatically, just create it as a formula field and use already predefined function DATE.